# Screen flashes randomly when using overridePendingTransition on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, animation, transition

This problem only happens sometimes on Jelly Bean 4.1 and 4.2 (tested on Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4).
Here is how I use `overridePendingTransition`

When starts a new Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transition_right_to_left,
                    R.anim.transition_right_to_left_out);
```

When finish an Activity to back to previous one

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transition_left_to_right, R.anim.transition_left_to_right_out);
```

transition_left_to_right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
android:toXDelta="0" 
android:duration="@integer/transition_duration"/>
```

transition_left_to_right_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="100%p" 
android:duration="@integer/transition_duration"/>
```

transition_right_to_left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="100%p"
android:toXDelta="0" 
android:duration="@integer/transition_duration"/>
```

transition_right_to_left_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="-100%p" 
android:duration="@integer/transition_duration"/>
```

And this is how screen flashes: http://youtu.be/TUKRz2yVF6Q (only happens from 01:00)

Please tell me if you know whats wrong with my code and why the device screen sometimes flashes? Thank you.

Edit: Tried to use ActivityOptions on Jelly Bean but it did not help

Comment: Is the problem coming on one specific ANDROID device or every android device supporting jelly bean?

Comment: I don't know because I don't have many devices to test except Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4.

Comment: But you can try it on Different Emulators with different OS versions

Comment: Try to increase animation duration and check if you can reproduce flashes

Comment: Currently transition_duration = 400 ms, after change to 800 (very very slow) the problem still persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same issue.
I was able to solve it by changing the interpolator to linear_interpolator instead of accelerate_decelerate_interpolator.

Comment: My pleasure, if you posted this question on other forums, please share this solution there as well...

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following line to your both animation XML files

```
 android:fillAfter="true"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but this did not help, and I think animation for overridePendingTransition doesn't need fillAfter.

Comment: `fillBefore` then? flashing can occur if the very first frame of the animation is drawn after the static(non-animated) view was drawn - for example it is likely to happen on `transition_left_to_right` since target view is drawn on the screen at first, and starts to move out of the screen as soon as animation starts

Comment: FillBefore cannot help also.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you have the "Don't keep activities" option turned on in the Developer Options section in settings?

Comment: I'm sorry that "Don't keep activities" option is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by delaying Activity transitions and using some view element as a shared element transition "anchor."

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_score);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // Postpone the shared element enter transition.
        postponeEnterTransition();
    }
}
```

Now you just need to call 'scheduleStartPostponedTransition()' from a point in your app where everything should be displayed on the screen.  This technique works very well and solves the screen flash problem when switching activities.

```
//
// Schedules the shared element transition to be started immediately
// after the shared element has been measured and laid out within the
// activity's view hierarchy. Some common places where it might make
// sense to call this method are:
//
// (1) Inside a Fragment's onCreateView() method (if the shared element
//     lives inside a Fragment hosted by the called Activity).
//
// (2) Inside a Picasso Callback object (if you need to wait for Picasso to
//     asynchronously load/scale a bitmap before the transition can begin).
//
// (3) Inside a LoaderCallback's onLoadFinished() method (if the shared
//     element depends on data queried by a Loader).
//
public void scheduleStartPostponedTransition(final ImageView sharedElement) {
    LogHelper.v(TAG, "scheduleStartPostponedTransition");
    sharedElement.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    sharedElement.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        startPostponedEnterTransition();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

See http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/03/activity-postponed-shared-element-transitions-part3b.html

Comment: Transition API which you propose had been added in API v20 - Jelly Bean is API v16

Answer (score -1):

Silly suggestion but have you tried changing the ordering of animation/finish()?

Like this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transition_left_to_right, R.anim.transition_left_to_right_out);
finish();
```

Comment: I'm sorry but Android document said that overridePendingTransition must be called immediately after finish() or startActivity() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)) . I already tried but of course it could not help.